# How to get the flash related source files from the swf file?

Tags: flash

I have a small flash project. I created a SWF from the flash sources.
Unfortunately all my flash sources related to the project are deleted.

I left with the SWF file. Is there any way that I can retrieve all the flash source files from the swf file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tools available from the internet.
For example [SWF Decrypt](http://www.swfdecrypt.com/SWFDecrypt_win.zip) which can work only for ActionScript 3.0 files.

There are some more Shareware files available. We can get them by searching in google.